# Can I share my external hard drive used for backup with other item?

Tags: backup, external-hdd, deja-dup

I bought a pretty large external hard drive to backup my computer with and I have used Deja Dup a couple times.

I noticed I have a directory DDBackup on my external hard drive now.  Can I use my external hard drive to store other things outside of the DDBackup directory?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why not.  Now keep in mind depending on what backup software you have, and the type of backup that you're using, it may not back up those items that are on the same backup drive.

Also be careful when deleting anything from that drive, so it won't affect the backed up data.  I would recommend that you create a separate partition for normal day-to-day use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use it for other things.  Any files out of that DDBackup directory will not bother Deja Dup.

(Truthfully, even putting files *inside* that directory won't bother Deja Dup, as it only pays attention to its own files.)